# Combining a Vector

Tags: r, list, vector

I have a data frame (called honey) that looks like:

```
Importer    year    tons    USD
Japan       2010    523     776
Thailand    2010    1095    975
Singapore   2010    1       2
...
```

I want to parse out the distinct countries, and add one to the list in my code.

```
unique(honey$Importer)
```

Returns the expected result; a list of 8 countries:

```
[1] Japan                    Thailand                
[3] Singapore                China                   
[5] Malaysia                 United States of America
[7] Canada                   Taipei, Chinese         
8 Levels: Canada China Japan Malaysia Singapore ... United States of America
```

But when I try to add one, like so:

```
c(unique(honey$Importer),'Myanmar')
```

I get:

```
[1] "3"       "7"       "5"       "2"       "4"       "8"      
[7] "1"       "6"       "Myanmar"
```

What makes this weird - and hard for me to understand - is that if I choose a different column, I get exactly what I'd expect:

```
c(unique(honey$year),'Myanmar')
[1] "2010"    "2011"    "2012"    "2013"    "2014"    "2015"   
[7] "Myanmar"
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Importer` is a factor, not a character vector, so the following gives a character vector of its levels plus the new one: `c(levels(honey$Importer), "Myanmar")`  Alternately define Importer as a character vector rather than a factor in the first place.

Comment: one more (dumb) question: when I load in data (I used read.csv), "Importer" obviously defaulted to Factor. Is that how R always reads strings unless you tell it not to, or is there some other rule that allowed you to know it was a factor object? I'm a bit confused about that. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Use `read.csv(..., as.is = TRUE)` to avoid automatic conversion to factor (or use the somewhat longer `stringsAsFactors` argument).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert to `character` as `year` is `factor` class.

```
c(as.character(unique(honey$Importer)),'Myanmar')
```

The `typeof` factor is `integer`, so when we concatenate a `factor` with `character` or other class, it gets converted to `integer`.

Comment: thank you!! I never would've figured that out on my own. (Noob. Teaching myself.)